# C# User input loop and array. (Homework)

Tags: c#

I'm new to posting here, but am a long time user. I am having some issues with this bit of homework. I've gotten it mostly done by myself but I am stumped by this loop. So, basically I need to take an array, send it to a new function, loop through it, and ask the user how much each item costs as it loops. Then, take that answer and put it back into a new array. My issue is that I don't know how to get the user input out of the for loop and into the array to be able to return it to my Main method. I am only allowed to use techniques taught in the class to solve this, making it a bit more challenging. For example, I can use any types of loops, conditionals, arrays, and lists etc. Thank you in advance, I know this may seem pretty obvious to most, but I'm just getting started with C#.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cookieArray.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine("What is the cost of {0} cookies?", cookieArray[i]);
  string costString = Console.ReadLine();
}
  string costString = Console.ReadLine();
  string[] cookieCost = new string[] { costString };
  return cookieCost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to get the user input out of the for loop and into
>   the array?

You can create an array of string outside loop and add user inputs(string) to the particular index of an string array.

In your case you created string array after for loop and added only one value to in string array.

Update your code,

```
//This will create new array for cookie cost.  
string[] cookieCost = new string[cookieArray.Length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < cookieArray.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine("What is the cost of {0} cookies?", cookieArray[i]);

  //Here you will store cost of cookies into an array 
  cookieCost[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
//Return cookieCost array to the main function
return cookieCost;
```

I would prefer to use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) over an array, because capacity of List can be increased as per our need and it provides lot of extension methods compare to an array

---

Below question is as per your recent comment

> How to convert user input into decimal and store it in an array?

There are two ways to do it,

1. Create decimal array at very first place and convert user input into decimal and store it in an array.
2. Using `Array.ConvertAll()` create new decimal array from string array.

**Using double array**

- Instead of string array create an double array and parse string input into double

```
  //This will create new array for cookie cost.  
  double[] cookieCost = new double[cookieArray.Length]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < cookieArray.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("What is the cost of {0} cookies?", cookieArray[i]);

    //Here you will store cost of cookies into an array 
    cookieCost[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  //Return cookieCost array to the main function
  return cookieCost;
```

**Using Array function**

- Pass string array to Array.ConvertAll() function to create new double array.

```
//Here cookieCost is of type string array.
double cookieCostDouble = Array.ConvertAll(cookieCost, double.Parse);
```

Comment: @MickiStafford, I added comment to explain each line of code. First understand what changes I made. What was your mistake. If you need any explanation let me know. Finally if my answer satisfies your need then accept it by green tick

Comment: Hey again, thank you for your additions, I definitely see what I did wrong now. I have one more question that I forgot to mention in my original post. I need these user inputs converted into decimals so I can work with them and eventually add them. I dont believe I am allowed to convert the entire array, rather I need to convert as the loop goes, then output. Thank you again, loops have been really confusing for me to learn.

Comment: @MickiStafford, I updated my answer. Kindly look into it